# Why am I getting a Identifier expected error

Tags: java, identifier

```
import java.util.*;

public class Students
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    Student s1=new Student();//creates object of class aircraft
    Student s2=new Student();
    //or
    //Student s1,s2
    //s1=new Student();
    //s2=new Student();
    String str;
    int i;
    //str=s1.getname();
   } 
}
class Student{ //extends Students{
   String name; 
   int 1;  ?<Identifier> expected? 
   int 2;  ?<Identifier> expected?
   int 3;  
   }
 }
```

in the last three lines i get identifier expected. why? The student class is supposed to store the name, and three test scores.

Comment: its on the last line too where it says int 3;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, variables are not allowed to start with numbers - `1` is an invalid variable name (though `num1` is valid).  See [the naming requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming).

To fix your code, I would rename them `int var1`, `int var2`, `int var3`.  (Though better names would be better - try something more descriptive)

Comment: @DomenicoGalati: Is this sample code in the book then? Which book?

Comment: fundamentals of java AP computer science essentials for the a and ab exams, Lambert/Osborne

Comment: mine is a little twisted from the original example

Answer (score 0):

You look to be trying to declare a variable and give it a value but you haven't provided a name for the variable.  Those lines should probably be something like this:

```
int n1 = 1;
int n2 = 2;
int n3 = 3;
```

Comment: Sorry to bug you but i am new and I was also wondering how would i be able to create a method inside of the Student class. To do things like average out the variables and such

Comment: @DomenicoGalati, that's a completely different question so it is not appropriate to answer it right here.  I would suggest that you read a Java tutorial or two because writing methods is pretty fundamental.  If you write some code and it doesn't work, then you can post back with a new question and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names in Java can not start with numbers. Try this instead:

```
class Student{ 
   String name; 
   int test1;  
   int test2;  
   int test3;  
   }
 }
```